# Exclude null value during full outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, null, full-outer-join

How to join these two tables with excluding all null values?

And Instead of UserId in 2nd table I want the user name from first table information.

[image]

Comment: Some text format sample table data would be nice, and the expected result too...

Comment: If you want to exclude all nulls, why would you use a full outer join?

Comment: Without seeing any actual query I can only say: add `WHERE LogoutTime IS NOT NULL` to your SQL statement.

Comment: 1. I don't think you need a full outer join; 2. Mention column name where you don't want nulls to come; 3. Give an example - expected result; 4. Tell us what you tried. Flagging Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve desire result by using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT UserProfile.*
FROM UserProfile
INNER JOIN UserLoginHistory ON UserProfile.UserId = UserLoginHistory.UserId AND UserLoginHistory.LogoutTime IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are two options(You didn't specified which columns come from which table)

A) You want to get only rows without null values and in that case its:

```
SELECT *  --(columns that you want)
FROM UserProfile t 
FULL OUTER JOIN UserLoginHistory s
ON t.UserId = s.UserId
AND s.LogoutTime IS NOT NULL
```

Or if only the logout time comes from the second table, you need an inner join instead of full join and in that case:

```
SELECT *  --(columns that you want)
FROM UserProfile t
INNER JOIN UserLoginHistory s
ON t.UserId = s.UserId
AND s.LogoutTime IS NOT NULL
```